# Считать строку из файла, посчитать кол-во символов и "присвоить" ее классу исходя из кол-ва символов. С++

Tags: c++, файловый-ввод-вывод

Есть файл .txt в нем строки типа

```
1-я строка:  1) "какой-то текст" 2) какой-то текст 3)...
2-я строка:  1) "какой-то текст" 2) какой-то текст 3)...
```

Как присвоить строку классу исходя из кол-ва символов в строке? Например строка из 100 символов присваивается классу `Stosimb`. Это весь код, который смог написать.
p.s. Компилируемый код.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

/*class Msg
{
Public:
Msg(){}
Msg(string ms)
{
this->ms = ms;
}
void Print()
    {cout <<  ms << endl;   }
    char ms;
}*/

int main()
{
    //ifstream fin;
    fstream fs;
    fs.open("myfile.txt", fstream::in | fstream::app);
    while(!fs.eof())
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        string msg;
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        getline(fs, msg);
        cout << msg << " ";
        cout << msg.length() << " characters\n"; 
        /*while(fin.read((char*)&msg, sizeof(Msg)))
        {
        ms.Print();
        }*/
    }
    fs.close();
    //ifs.close();
}
```

Comment: а можете немного больше описать задачу? какая именно задача решается и что в результате хочется получить?

Comment: Код не компилируется, приведите [mre]

Comment: и чем это поможет? а ничем. а ошибки они незначительны и не мешают пониманию кода.

Comment: @dIm0n теперь компилируется

Comment: @KoVadim я бы не называл ошибки компиляции незначительными. Если участник захочет дать ответ, используя код автора, то ему придётся исправлять их самостоятельно, чтобы его решение работало

Comment: `while(!fs.eof())` - опять и снова.

Comment: @KoVadim более 1000 строк, все важны, но нужно выделить те, в которых больше информации(т.е. символов). Также, каждая строка имеет свои разделы(обозначены цифрами). В итоге получаем классы, которые являются строками с обозначенной информативностью в них. Позже можно в самих классах сделать разделение на разделы имеющихся строк.

Comment: то есть, нужно написать построчное чтение (это просто), функцию "важности строки" (тут похоже просто длина?) и "вывод/выделение" (в  отдельный файл).

Comment: @KoVadim вывод нужен для иллюстрации, того что класс получил эту строку. В дальнейшем будет работа с классами отдельная.

Comment: Вы понимаете разницу между классом и объектом этого класса? классу сложно "получить строку". Это как чертеж дома получил жителей.

Comment: @KoVadim я обобщил, понятно что получит объект класса.

Comment: нет, не нужно обобщать. "обобщая задачу", Вы усложняете ее для нас и для себя. Но вот правило "важности строки" или ее классификации Вы так и не привели. Очень похоже, что Вы парсите какие то логи и Вам нужно обновлять счетчики/метрики по данным лога

Comment: @KoVadim "важность строки" это наличие в ней информации, чем больше в ней символов, тем она "важнее". Если вы думаете, что я хочу заниматься чем-то плохим, то вы не правы, могу сказать для чего мне это))

Comment: я не сказал, что Вы занимаетесь плохим. Парсинг логов - это обычное законное дело.

Comment: Не надо копировать строку несколько раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая все вышесказанное в комментариях, сделаем простой пример.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Msg
{
public:
  Msg(){}
  Msg(string ms) :m_ms{ms} {}
    void Print() {
        cout <<  m_ms << endl;
    }
private:
    string m_ms;
};

int main()
{
    fstream fs("file");
    if (!fs) {
        cout << "ups\n"; // если файл не открылся, нужно бежать
        return 1;
    }
    string msg;
    while(getline(fs, msg)) // если строк нет, тут будет false и цикл завершится
    {
        if (msg.length() > 10) { // эта строка избрана, она достаточно длинная
            Msg m(msg); // "передадим классу строку" (да, звучит некорректно)
            m.Print(); // что то сделаем, напечатаем
        }
    }
}
```

Будут уточнения в условии, будут уточнения в коде.

Comment: Благодарю, хороший код. Буду в нем разбираться.